# .NET Error sending email

Tags: c#, .net, email

```
try
{
  MailMessage m = new MailMessage("testesmtpmi@hotmail.com", "myEmail@gmail.com", "Situação", "Oi, tudo bem?");
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testesmtpmi@hotmail.com", "xxxx");
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  smtp.Send(m);
  Console.WriteLine("sucesso");
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

whats wrong in here please?
its join in catch and say Failure sending email

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a crystal ball allowing me to read your mind and guess the full exception trace you are getting. Hopefully someone does have such an artifact and will be able to help you. Only time will show.

Comment: Can you write out the full ex.ToString() instead of ex.Message and post that?  The additional details will be useful.

Comment: @Darin - Your comment reminded me of this http://imgur.com/jacoj :)

Comment: Ack! Ninja'd in exceptionally snarky fashion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Why can't I send email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908215/net-why-cant-i-send-email)

Answer (score 0):

```
    try
    {
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage("WindowsLiveUserName@live.com", "myEmail@gmail.com", "Situação", "Oi, tudo bem?");
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;            
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("WindowsLiveUserName@live.com", "YourPassword", "");

        smtp.Send(m);
        Console.WriteLine("sucesso");
    }
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```